# Get points within maximum distance from any point in GeoPandas

Tags: distance, attribute-joins, spatial-join, geopandas, shapely

Given a set of points (with meters coordinates), I am trying to create lines between them. But I don't want to create lines of each pair of points, Iwant to create thoses lines if the distance between two points is inferior or equal to a threshold value (let's say 1000m).

And from there, I am quite lost. The `distance()` function only returns a `GeoSerie` of the points with themselves, so all my values are at `0.0`.
I am also facing issues with the `buffer()` function, not knowing how to properly use the `GeoSerie` result once computed.

From what I tested so far:

- `intersection()` returns a `GeoSerie` with only one reference,
- `sjoin` does not work with `GeoSeries`
- converting the buffer `GeoSerie` to a `GeoDataFrame` results in `AttributeError: No geometry data set yet (expected in column 'geometry'`

Any leads about how to achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have one geoseries with Points (for example you want to compare Point 1 to Point 2, Point 1 to Point 3,... ):

```
import geopandas as gpd
from itertools import combinations
from shapely.geometry import LineString

df = gpd.read_file(r"C:\data\vk_riks_Sweref_99_TM_shape\vagk\riks\js_riks.shp")

series = df.geometry
max_distance = 15000

points_within = []
for i1,i2 in combinations(range(0,series.shape[0]-1),2):  #Iterate over all pairs/combinations of indices
    if 0<series[i1].distance(series[i2])<=max_distance:
        points_within.append([series[i1],series[i2]])

geoms = [LineString(pointpair) for pointpair in points_within]
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.GeoSeries(geoms))
df2.crs = 'epsg:3006' #Adjust
df2.to_file(r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\lines_within.shp')
```

[image]